# .htaccess "Order allow,deny Deny from all" - works partially

Tags: apache, .htaccess, modx-revolution

Good afternoon. Actually the problem is in the title. I Use Modx. In folder i create .thaccess with code

```
  Order allow,deny
  Deny from all
```

This command hides the folder from external access, and also, some types of files, for example - ".pdf", become inaccessible. But ".jpg" files are still opened by direct link, as well as ".word" or ".rar" are downloaded. Tell me how to deal with this problem? thanks

Comment: Did you wrap instructions from above with <Files> or <FilesMatch> tags? If so please let me know full code text.

Comment: did not write tags, I provided the full text of what is in htaccess

Comment: Are you sure that wasn't just your browser cache tricking you? If not, then we need more info. Are the files requested directly, or are any rewrites involved maybe, etc.

Comment: this is strange, instructions from above should work for jpg,rar etc. other files too.. maybe something overrides these instructions with a higher priority?